# Target class [PagesController] does not exist. Why?

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return 'INDEX';
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working?
I am using laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

because

```
[PagesController::class, 'index']
```

is pointing to a different `namespace` than the one you are in, so you should use

```
[\App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class, 'index']
```